# 64bit Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit)

Why Visual Studio does not have a 64bit version?