# Visual Studio 2010 choose version to Download? (x86/x64)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, x86, 64-bit

Generally wondering if there are multiple versions of Visual Studio 2010 to download i.e. I can only find x86 and unsure if this is the version I want for Win7 x64 [which I am running]

Are there multiple versions available or is the only release version x86 which just install x64 components?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 64 bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit) Also [Visual Studio 2010 download questions are being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348615/cleaning-up-visual-studio-2010-download-questions).

Answer (score 9):

There won't be  x64 version of VS2010. For some explanations take a look at [Rico Mariani's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx).

Comment: @tom the only benefit is the ability to access more than 4gb of memory.  You'd have to have an insanely large solution to need that.

Comment: Also, that blog post explains the situation very well.  Nice find, Frank.

Comment: @Will that's not the only restriction, [there's a lot of really counter-intuitive restrictions caused by VS being 32 bit when using 64 bit libraries in an application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800388/cannot-place-user-control-on-form/16163310#comment72265436_16163310) I've had to add code and mess with my design to work around this even though my application has no reason to be anything other than 64 bit, aside from compatibility with VS's designer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no 64 bit version of Visual Studio 2010.

See http://news.softpedia.com/news/Don-039-t-Hold-Your-Breath-for-64-bit-Visual-Studio-113943.shtml.

According to the article "customers are better off running the development platform in 32-bit emulation mode on top of 64-bit Windows. And while saying nothing about 64-bit support beyond Visual Studio 2010, the lesson for developers is don't hold your breath for x64 VS."

Not that answer you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no x64 version of Visual Studio...

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Don-039-t-Hold-Your-Breath-for-64-bit-Visual-Studio-113943.shtml

In summary, there's no lift from a 64-bit compiler or IDE.