# Unable to view my form in the form designer

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I added a new class to my C# project. Very simple, and based on many examples I have found:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GENIO_Viewer
{
    class DBTableLayoutPanel : TableLayoutPanel
    {
        public DBTableLayoutPanel() : base()
        {
            DoubleBuffered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I then edited the designer class file to use the revised object (code cut down):

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.tableLayoutPanel = new DBTableLayoutPanel();
    // tableLayoutPanel
    // 
    this.tableLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true;
    this.tableLayoutPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    this.tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 1;
    this.tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross;
    this.tableLayoutPanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.tableLayoutPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 24);
    this.tableLayoutPanel.Name = "tableLayoutPanel";
    this.tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 1;
    this.tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 359);
    this.tableLayoutPanel.TabIndex = 4;
}
```

It compiles OK. But when I go to display teh form in the editor I get a problem:

[image: Errors]

Why is this? I can't work out what I have to do to fix it.

Update:

This is full form definition for the designer file. It only works if I comment out the DBTableLayoutPanel lines and replace with the commented out lines. Confused. :

```
using System;

namespace GENIO_Viewer
{
    partial class GENIO_Viewer_Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();

                m_moduleTD_Tb.Dispose();
                m_hostApp.Dispose();
                m_sysSrv.Dispose();

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                Teigha.Core.Globals.odgsUninitialize();
                Teigha.Core.Globals.odrxUninitialize();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(GENIO_Viewer_Form));
            this.toolStripButton1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
            this.statusStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip();
            this.toolStripCoordinate = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
            this.toolStripProgressBar = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar();
            this.toolStripStatusLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
            this.toolStripCoordinates = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
            //this.tableLayoutPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.tableLayoutPanel = new GENIO_Viewer.DBTableLayoutPanel();
            this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.menuFile = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.menuFile_LoadGenio = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.menuFile_SaveAutoCAD = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.toolStripSeparator1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
            this.menuFile_RecentFile = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.toolStripSeparator2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
            this.menuFile_Exit = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.menuView = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.menuViewCodeEditor = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.toolStripSeparator3 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
            this.menuView_ZoomExtents = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.menuView_ZoomWindow = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.toolStrip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomWindow = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomExtents = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
            this.statusStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.toolStrip.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // toolStripButton1
            // 
            this.toolStripButton1.Name = "toolStripButton1";
            this.toolStripButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 23);
            // 
            // statusStrip1
            // 
            this.statusStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.toolStripCoordinate,
            this.toolStripProgressBar,
            this.toolStripStatusLabel,
            this.toolStripCoordinates});
            this.statusStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 383);
            this.statusStrip1.Name = "statusStrip1";
            this.statusStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 22);
            this.statusStrip1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.statusStrip1.Text = "statusStrip";
            // 
            // toolStripCoordinate
            // 
            this.toolStripCoordinate.AutoSize = false;
            this.toolStripCoordinate.Name = "toolStripCoordinate";
            this.toolStripCoordinate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 17);
            // 
            // toolStripProgressBar
            // 
            this.toolStripProgressBar.AutoSize = false;
            this.toolStripProgressBar.Name = "toolStripProgressBar";
            this.toolStripProgressBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 16);
            // 
            // toolStripStatusLabel
            // 
            this.toolStripStatusLabel.AutoSize = false;
            this.toolStripStatusLabel.Name = "toolStripStatusLabel";
            this.toolStripStatusLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(257, 17);
            this.toolStripStatusLabel.Spring = true;
            this.toolStripStatusLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            // 
            // toolStripCoordinates
            // 
            this.toolStripCoordinates.Name = "toolStripCoordinates";
            this.toolStripCoordinates.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true;
            this.tableLayoutPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            this.tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 1;
            this.tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross;
            this.tableLayoutPanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 24);
            this.tableLayoutPanel.Name = "tableLayoutPanel";
            this.tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 1;
            this.tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 359);
            this.tableLayoutPanel.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.menuFile,
            this.menuView});
            this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 24);
            this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 5;
            this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
            // 
            // menuFile
            // 
            this.menuFile.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.menuFile_LoadGenio,
            this.menuFile_SaveAutoCAD,
            this.toolStripSeparator1,
            this.menuFile_RecentFile,
            this.toolStripSeparator2,
            this.menuFile_Exit});
            this.menuFile.Name = "menuFile";
            this.menuFile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
            this.menuFile.Text = "&File";
            this.menuFile.DropDownOpening += new System.EventHandler(this.menuFile_DropDownOpening);
            // 
            // menuFile_LoadGenio
            // 
            this.menuFile_LoadGenio.Name = "menuFile_LoadGenio";
            this.menuFile_LoadGenio.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(172, 22);
            this.menuFile_LoadGenio.Text = "Load GENIO File";
            this.menuFile_LoadGenio.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuFile_LoadGenio_Click);
            // 
            // menuFile_SaveAutoCAD
            // 
            this.menuFile_SaveAutoCAD.Name = "menuFile_SaveAutoCAD";
            this.menuFile_SaveAutoCAD.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(172, 22);
            this.menuFile_SaveAutoCAD.Text = "Save AutoCAD File";
            this.menuFile_SaveAutoCAD.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuFile_SaveAutoCAD_Click);
            // 
            // toolStripSeparator1
            // 
            this.toolStripSeparator1.Name = "toolStripSeparator1";
            this.toolStripSeparator1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 6);
            // 
            // menuFile_RecentFile
            // 
            this.menuFile_RecentFile.Name = "menuFile_RecentFile";
            this.menuFile_RecentFile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(172, 22);
            this.menuFile_RecentFile.Text = "Recent File";
            // 
            // toolStripSeparator2
            // 
            this.toolStripSeparator2.Name = "toolStripSeparator2";
            this.toolStripSeparator2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 6);
            // 
            // menuFile_Exit
            // 
            this.menuFile_Exit.Name = "menuFile_Exit";
            this.menuFile_Exit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(172, 22);
            this.menuFile_Exit.Text = "E&xit";
            this.menuFile_Exit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuFile_Exit_Click);
            // 
            // menuView
            // 
            this.menuView.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.menuViewCodeEditor,
            this.toolStripSeparator3,
            this.menuView_ZoomExtents,
            this.menuView_ZoomWindow});
            this.menuView.Name = "menuView";
            this.menuView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 20);
            this.menuView.Text = "&View";
            this.menuView.DropDownOpening += new System.EventHandler(this.menuView_DropDownOpening);
            // 
            // menuViewCodeEditor
            // 
            this.menuViewCodeEditor.Name = "menuViewCodeEditor";
            this.menuViewCodeEditor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(153, 22);
            this.menuViewCodeEditor.Text = "Code Editor";
            this.menuViewCodeEditor.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuViewCodeEditor_Click);
            // 
            // toolStripSeparator3
            // 
            this.toolStripSeparator3.Name = "toolStripSeparator3";
            this.toolStripSeparator3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 6);
            // 
            // menuView_ZoomExtents
            // 
            this.menuView_ZoomExtents.Name = "menuView_ZoomExtents";
            this.menuView_ZoomExtents.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(153, 22);
            this.menuView_ZoomExtents.Text = "Zoom &Extents";
            this.menuView_ZoomExtents.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuView_ZoomExtents_Click);
            // 
            // menuView_ZoomWindow
            // 
            this.menuView_ZoomWindow.Name = "menuView_ZoomWindow";
            this.menuView_ZoomWindow.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(153, 22);
            this.menuView_ZoomWindow.Text = "Zoom &Window";
            this.menuView_ZoomWindow.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuView_ZoomWindow_Click);
            // 
            // toolStrip
            // 
            this.toolStrip.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomWindow,
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomExtents});
            this.toolStrip.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 24);
            this.toolStrip.Name = "toolStrip";
            this.toolStrip.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 25);
            this.toolStrip.TabIndex = 6;
            this.toolStrip.Text = "toolStrip";
            // 
            // toolStripButton_ZoomWindow
            // 
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomWindow.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomWindow.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("toolStripButton_ZoomWindow.Image")));
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomWindow.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomWindow.Name = "toolStripButton_ZoomWindow";
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomWindow.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 22);
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomWindow.Text = "Zoom Window";
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomWindow.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripButton_ZoomWindow_Click);
            // 
            // toolStripButton_ZoomExtents
            // 
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomExtents.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomExtents.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("toolStripButton_ZoomExtents.Image")));
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomExtents.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomExtents.Name = "toolStripButton_ZoomExtents";
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomExtents.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 22);
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomExtents.Text = "Zoom Extents";
            this.toolStripButton_ZoomExtents.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripButton_ZoomExtents_Click);
            // 
            // GENIO_Viewer_Form
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 405);
            this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.statusStrip1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
            this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
            this.Name = "GENIO_Viewer_Form";
            this.Text = "GENIO Viewer";
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.GENIO_Viewer_Form_FormClosing);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.GENIO_Viewer_Form_Load);
            this.statusStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.statusStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.toolStrip.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.toolStrip.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton toolStripButton1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip statusStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripStatusLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar toolStripProgressBar;
        //private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel;
        private GENIO_Viewer.DBTableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuFile;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuView;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuView_ZoomExtents;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuView_ZoomWindow;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuFile_LoadGenio;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuFile_SaveAutoCAD;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip toolStrip;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton toolStripButton_ZoomWindow;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton toolStripButton_ZoomExtents;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripCoordinates;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripCoordinate;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuFile_RecentFile;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuFile_Exit;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuViewCodeEditor;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator3;
    }
}
```

Update: This also happens when I inherit `DataGridView` and set `DoubleBuffered`. Renders editor inoperable.

Comment: Have you tried closing all designers and then Clean and Rebuild the Solution and open designer again?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did not seem to resolve it.

Comment: If simply cleaning and rebuilding the solution or reopening visual studio and rebuilding after deleting bin and obj didn't solve the problem, take a look at this question and answer [Can't view designer when coding a form in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298865/cant-view-designer-when-coding-a-form-in-c-sharp) You may find the question and answer useful.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I can't seem to resolve this matter from that link either. :(

Comment: That link doesn't solve the problem directly. But shares some important and interesting information about how the designer works. By having such information, usually you can solve designer issues.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I am still encountering the issue. It is not clear to me what to change. I have also examined the CSPROJ file.

Comment: this issue mostly occur when you add a control on form and also add event on code behinde ,but later you change or remove code from code behinde and in designrer it reference is exists , better solution for this are to check recently working form and remove code one by one and test

Comment: remove the table panael code and add again then try

Comment: I have just tried this. No joy. But I can create a new project, drag it in, and it is OK. Maybe I have to re-create the whole project?

Comment: @NazirUllah Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this question:

[Cannot Place User Control on Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800388/cannot-place-user-control-on-form)

In one of the answers it spoke about changing the build mode. I had set it to **x64** bit build mode because of the DLL files my application depends on. If set to **Any CPU** I get these build errors:

```
//1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "TD_SwigCoreMgd, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8e28356228e490a2, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
//1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "TD_SwigDbMgd, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ccc28765cdf0a88, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
//1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "TG_SwigDbMgd, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e973a5aff9b959, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
```

So it occured to me to set the application back to Any CPU, do a clean and rebuild, and voila, I can now edit my forms. But, I have to set it back to x64 afterwards. It is annoying. But I see no other way.