# Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 on 64-bit Machines?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I know many have asked the same question but I am still confused that does Visual studio 2008 or 2010 works with 64-bit computers?
Here in this post the answer is that he can run Visual studio on Windows 64 bit OS? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 both work perfectly on 64-bit machines using the x86 installation.

Comment: and here it says No? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit

Comment: @Zai: There is not a x64 bit version of visual studio.  However visual studio runs just fine on x64 machines.  I have both 2008 and 2010 running on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: That means there isn't a specific flavour of VS that runs natively on 64-bit.  There isn't a 64-bit version of Office either (except the new 2010 RTM) but people can use it.  Windows has WOW which allows 32-bit apps to run on a 64-bit system.

Comment: No, it says that there isn't a 64bit only version but that the x86 version works fine on 64bit os.

Comment: Thanks, this is what my confusion was! what I have been thinking is that we must use VS 64 bit to use with 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  They run on 64-bit machines.  The included compiler can create 32-bit or 64-bit output.

Answer (score 0):

Both run on 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Though if you use the *Edit and Continue* functionality it won't work for 64bit apps and on a 64bit OS it seems to default to 64bit apps so you have to remember to change the target if you want to use that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Both can run on 64-bit machines.

Visual Studio is not available in 64 bit version, so internals will be in 32bit and they can run in 64bit (WOW enabled).

Also compiler can generate 32bit and 64bit output.