# The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Yes I already searched and the solution on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683255/the-designer-could-not-be-shown-for-this-file-because-none-of-the-classes-within) didnt work, my scenario is different.

I have a winform application, very simple, it was working, and now the error on the title of this post is shown when I try to open the form.
The only thing I have done is installed VS11 developer preview and vs 2010 SP1.

Any idea how to fix this?>

Comment: Do you have any constructors in your classes which need parameters?

Comment: its a standard winform, I created the form with one method, and call the method from a button click, thats it.

Comment: Can you post the code of the designer or is it confidential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve it, I checked on properties of the project and the framework selected was .net 4.0 client profile.

I changed it to .net 4.0 and then it worked.

by the way what does it mean client profile, what is it for??

Comment: Client profile loads fewer DLLs in an attempt to be lighter for distribution... it's the default and it always causes headaches.

Comment: I had this problem with .net 4.0 framework! and I solved my problem by changing framework to another version and again change it to version 4.0

Comment: I had this problem after creating a new local repository with the 4.7.1 framework. I changed version back to 4.7 and then 4.7.1 again and it worked again.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this happen to me. I was banging my head on my desk in frustration as to why. Closed and reopened Visual Studio and it was fixed. Weird.