# Error migrating winform .net framework 3.5 to 4

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

hi i have similiar problem with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683255/the-designer-could-not-be-shown-for-this-file-because-none-of-the-classes-within) but i can't find anyway to solve it...
start from my pathner create project with vs 2008 (framework 3.5) and when i try to migrate to vs 2010 so i can use framework 4...i get this error

```
The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed.
```

this is call stack for it

```
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.
         EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.
         PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.
         PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.
         VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.
         TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

i try to change back in vs 2010, target framework to 3.5 and i can still open designer view...any idea how i can migrate to .net framework 4.0

---

### **ADDING MORE INFORMATION**

from what @mark said..it's seem there is some reference which not compatible with framework 4...and he's right some reference in my project have warning symbol...
1. Microsoft.office.core version 2.4.0.0 (microsoft office 12.0 object library)
2. Microsoft.office.interop.excel version 1.6.00 (microsoft office 12.0 object library)
3. VBIDe version 5.3.0.0 (Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3)

but i still not know how to check compatibility that's reference to framework 4
because as far i get [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) is the best result i got from google with many keyword
and it's not give any hint about compatibility with framework 4

*"but i still can run program normally (export to excel) even in framework 4, i just can't open designer view"*

Comment: Basic question, but did you try to clean/rebuild?

Comment: Is this a basic winforms project or are you using any 3rd party controls or framework.

Comment: @Vache when i try rebuild, it's same error 'the designer can't be shown....' but clean run success...any idea?

Comment: @MarkHall as far as i know this project used 'microsoft.office.core', 'microsoft office.interop'. Actually i just continue this project from my previous pathner...anyway how to check if there is any 3d control or framework used?

Comment: @vache i try to rebuilt again but different than before..this time i get error 'task failed because 'Axlmp.exe' was not found....i try as error suggested install microsoft sdk but still get same error

Comment: Check the versions of the Microsoft office references and see if they are compatable with .net 4. To check for 3rd party Controls look in your project references to see what is there.

Comment: If this was my project I would make a backup of the entire solution/project first. I would  then remove the references that have the warning symbol by them by right clicking on the reference and selecting remove reference, then I would tight click on the reference folder in the solution explorer and select add reference and add them back. Then see if you still have an issue. The warning sign usually means that a reference can not be found.

Comment: @MarkHall that work's thanks...now i can open designer view after remove them..but when i try to add back it's still have warning sign...i try with random reference and all of them have warning sign..i wonder what it means?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46397/discussion-between-mark-hall-and-katik)

Answer (score 0):

Backup your project then clean(remove references that are not compatible) your project and it should be ok!

Comment: it's actually problem with visual studio installer.. i already try clean build too but no work....after i reinstall visual studio it's instantly work smooth