# error in Windows form

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I am creating a windows form in C++ and I get an error " The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed." But still program is debugging giving output but I cannot see designer.I reinstall visual but there is no difference.Please help me.

Comment: Please elaborate on your code, as in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683255/the-designer-could-not-be-shown-for-this-file-because-none-of-the-classes-within

Comment: The designer is quirky. Is your form the *first* class in the file? IIRC the designer can't deal with it otherwise. You should post some code, at least the structure of classes in your files.

Comment: Designer also requires a parameterless constructor.  Yes, please post some code.

Comment: Is it VS 2015? Check your settings: `text editor` > `c/c++` > `browsing/navigation` > `disable external dependencies folder`. Isn't it `true` by chance? I spent a few days trying to understand why my form editor would refuse to open a form, this turned out to be the cluprit for me. I set it to `false` and it works now.