# 'the type or namespace could not be found' in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2017

Every time I do a git pull from remote to update my branch, Visual Studio 2017 shows "the type or namespace could not be found" error in many files as I open them. Interestingly I don't see the problem in Visual Studio 2015 for the same projects/repo. The software builds fine in both versions of Visual Studio so it is a false error. Doing a Clean or Rebuild doesn't fix the problem. I end up re-cloning the repo from remote and then Visual Studio 2017 is happy. Any one knows how to fix this annoying problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the package-restore. If it fails, you get the issue.
You can try to unload and reload the projects, but I also still haven't found a way to avoid it.

Comment: I've unloaded and reloaded all projects, but I still got this message. I can build solution, but Intelli sense is not working for imported namespaces.

Comment: @FrenkyB Then try Marco Pavic‘s solution.

Comment: This is still happening, and this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: @VariableSquid Did you try any of the other solutions?

Comment: @Nikolaus Yes, it was to do with making a x64 only solution. I now have a development build for editing the forms, and another one for a 64 bit only build. Not the best. I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835360/c-sharp-winforms-designer-wont-open-because-it-cannot-find-type-in-same-assembl

Answer (score 6):

Unloading and reloading the project did not work work me.

Instead, I delete the hidden .suo file inside the project directory and everything started working again. The path is:

(project name) \ .vs \ (project name) \ v15 \ .suo

Comment: I've also did this and it's not working. Which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS 2017

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had csproj.user file that I've removed and then reloaded the project.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred in VS 2019 while participating in a C# Essential Training course. My solution is:

1. Save the entire project
2. Close project
3. Open project