# 'the type or namespace could not be found' in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

Intellisense is not working as supposed in VS 2019. It can not find classes from imported namespaces:

[image]

What I have already tried is unload and reload all projects, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819072/the-type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-in-visual-studio-2017), but it doesn't help. I would like to navigate with F12 to selected class, but intelli sense doesn't find it.

What else can I try? I am using VS2019 16.0.4 version, community edition.

Comment: Hi, does this issue only happens to this specific project? Have you already tried to delete the hidden folder .vs?

Comment: I've closed VS2019, deleted .vs folder. Intelli sense still not working.

Comment: Do you have other VS version like 2017? This issue happens in other vs version or not? If you create a new project to test it, it occurs or not?

Comment: I have VS2017. There is OK.

Comment: Could you please share some sample codes? I will try to test it in my vs 2019 and check if this issue can reproduce or not.

Comment: It's from my project, it's too big to post it here. But basically all referenced classes (from other projects) are showing as non-existing / intelli sense is not working.

Comment: Did you write the usings correctly and are the other projects really referenced?

Comment: @Nikolaus - yes, they are. This error is now gone, I guess with updates to VS.