# Is there a true 64-bit version of msvcr80.dll? If not, why not?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

***I have read the link*** that answers the question of whether there is a 64 bit version of Visual Studios ( [Visual Studio 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit) ).  The simple answer is ***No***, but the 32 bit Visual Studio development environment can produce 64-bit executables.

**Questions**:

1) Is there a 64 bit version of the Microsoft redistributable library **msvcr80.dll**?  I have installed the redistributable package on my Windows 7, 64 bit machine, and all the copies (7 in all) found in the winsxs sub-directory indicate in their *header sections* that they are 32 bit.

2) Isn't it true that:

a) 32-bit executables cannot load a 64-bit dll?

b) 64-bit executables cannot load a 32-bit dll?

c) if it is true that all versions of msvcr80.dll are tru )  32-bit, as indicated in the header sections of each, how can a 64-bit application built with Visual Studio use any of the functionality of this redistributable?

If someone has found a true 64-bit version of this file (msvcr80.dll) i.e. one in which the header section actually states that it is a 64-bit library, please point me to the link.

[New: Added image of BeyondCompare Viewer to show contents of msvcr80.dll header section, indicating dll is targeted for 32 bit use...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A69m.jpg)

Comment: Closing the loop here - Not long after posting this, I discovered that the 64bit version of the MS redistributable is _msvcr100.dll_, and is included in recent versions of Microsoft's SDK downloads.

Comment: no....  "msvcr80.dll" is the (release) runtime for Visual Studio 2005, there should be a 32bit in the WinSxS directory.  I don't know if 2005 had a 64bit version, but if it did, it would be in the system directory.  "msvcr100.dll" is the (release) runtime for Visual Studio 2010, it should also have a 32bit in the WinSxS and a 64bit in the System directory.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Not sure what `no....` refers to in your comment.  I have used msvcr100.dll, and I got it from a downloadable Microsoft Windows 7 SDK.  I agree it is distributed with the development environments such as Visual Studios, but is also available in SDK. (I edited this post just an hour or so ago, simply to point out where people could get the 64bit msvcrxxx.dll if they needed it without having the full MS Visual Studios)

Comment: `no...` refers to the fact that "msvcr100.dll" is NOT the 64bit version when "msvcr80.dll" is the 32bit.  They don't correspond in that way.  You have to use the version number of the dll that matches the Visual Studio used to build the executable.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Ah....  I seems I have made some wrong conclusions.  And my statement above is misleading.  Thank you,  I will edit it out.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beyond Compare isn't using the PE headers for what it's displaying - it's using version resources, and the `FILEOS` version resource for the x64 msvcr80.dll has the value `VOS_NT_WINDOWS32` (as far as I know there isn't a `VOS_NT_WINDOWS64`).

Use `dumpbin /headers` (or `link /dump /headers`) to get your information about the PE headers. You'll see that the x64 DLLs have the following info:

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to point out that msvcr80.dll is the crt runtime for visual studio 2005, not visual studio 2010 as indicated by your tag.

The dll in the winsxs amd64_xxx is a win64 dll.  Here is a dumpbin of the dll on my system:

```
C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.1833_none_88de3f632fb047bc>dumpbin /headers msvcr80.dll Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file msvcr80.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
               6 number of sections
        482BAB54 time date stamp Thu May 15 15:17:40 2008
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
            2022 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   DLL
```

Here is a dumpbin of the 32bit version:

```
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.1833_none_d08b763a442c70c2>dumpbin /headers msvcr80.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file msvcr80.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               5 number of sections
        482BB294 time date stamp Thu May 15 15:48:36 2008
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
            2102 characteristics
                   Executable
                   32 bit word machine
                   DLL
```

And for the answer to 2)

32bit applications can not load 64bit dll's and 64bit applications can not load 32dll's.

See [MSDN 64bit Process Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384231%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no 64-bit version of Visual Studio yet, all VS are 32-bit only.
2. VS is capable of building and debugging 64-bit executables.
3. If your OS is 64-bit, it does NOT mean you need 64-bit VC runtime for running the apps. If application is 32-bit, you need 32-bit runtime, and not 64-bit runtime. If application is 64-bit, yes, definitely you need 64-bit VC Runtime.
4. The VC runtime must match with the version you used to build the binaries (VC8, VC9 or VC10). And it must also match the service pack.
5. 32-bit binaries have 4 bytes addressing, and therefore it is not possible for 32-bit process to load 64-bit DLL. It goes true other way around also.