# 32bit Visual Studio generate 64bit executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a 64bit machine, if I installed 32bit visual studio, can I generate 64bit executable?

The actual problem is that I am moving my projection from Linux to Windows which uses C++11.
On the Windows I only have access to the 32bit version of Visual Studio 2013. I am wondering if it will work.

The project uses massive memory and C++11 features not supported by Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Open Configuration manager and add x64 configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, does it mean the 32bit and 64bit for VS is referring to the executable of VS itself?

Comment: Actually, I don't know whether 64-bit Visual Studio exists. But it can produce 64-bit executables.

Comment: there is no such thing as '32bit and 64bit VS' or '32bit and 64bit for VS'. There is VS, and a set of tools. One of those are the compiler/linker. And they can generate executable code for different platforms. Like 32bit/64bit/arm/..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio is a 32-bit application, [there is no 64-bit version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit). It can compile 64-bit executables.