# How do I get my .dlls to show bit at the end?

Tags: vb.net

When I build my .dlls using Visual Studio x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt (2010), I do not see (32 bit) at the end of the name.
For example all my .dlls show like this **EFile_CitationDocument_3_1_Xsl.dll** without 32 bit.
What do I need to do to show .dlls like this: **EFile_CitationDocument_3_1_Xsl.dll (32 bit)**

Comment: Are you asking how to rename a file in Windows?

Comment: I added an explanation of what I am doing and how. I hope this will help you help me.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to obtain assemblies in both, x32 and x64 versions, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246382/what-is-the-difference-between-x64-native-tools-command-prompt-and-x64-cross-too