# 64 bit version of Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, 32bit-64bit, x86-64

This might not be the right place to ask this, but I am going to give it a shot anyways...

I bought Visual Studio 2015 Professional, for some reason when I followed the download link it was only giving me the option to download 32bit.exe or 32bit.iso, well I want a 64bit version.

So then I logged into **visualstudioonline** and downloaded the ISO from there and still wasn't given an option to choose whether I want a 32bit version or a 64bit version. Yes, my laptop is 64bit and so is the Windows 10 OS that I am running.

I have called Microsoft and spent a glorious 4 hours being transferred all over the world a total of 15 times and having to repeat myself 15 times only to be transferred again and to no avail.

So can anyone tell me where I can get a 64bit version of Visual Studio 2015?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Visual-Studio-2015-still-a-32-bit-application

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the 32-bit version? Did it not install on your system? Do you need to produce and debug 64-bit code? 32-bit Visual Studio can do that.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I am working on a enterprise web application and is being deployed to Azure and the consultant has said that I need to be running a 64bit version for what we are doing. He has VS2015 installed and was given the option of 32bit and 64bit

Comment: I got a 32 bit community edition on my brand new laptop as well. Maybe the consultant just *thinks* he's running a 64 bit IDE?

Comment: There is no 64-bit version of the IDE. The 64-bit compilers are all included, as well as an x86-x64 cross-compiler.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I have no idea

Comment: tell him to open task manager and see if his VS is 32 or 64 bit

Comment: best consultant ever (well not surprising) - but anyway: the VS (= basically *just the editor*) is irrelevant to what you are producing in the end - if you need 64bit just change your project/compile settings accordingly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no 64bit VS edition

Comment: @Carsten, I wouldn't say that this is off topic because technology moves at a very fast pace and things could very well have changed, and sometimes when a search is being done ALOT of links are old

Comment: @Chris sure but why is this different from asking about a tool ... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 64 bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit)

Comment: I've voting to reopen this question - the correct answer is "There is no 64bit version of VS2015". There may well be a 64 bit of VS2016, or VS2020, who knows? It IS similar to [Visual Studio 64 bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2516436/345659) but specifically about 2015, so it IS different

Comment: @JumpingJezza There is no 64-bit VS2017 either.  RC just came out.  Also, how exactly is this question off topic?  If it *is* off-topic, which stack exchange site should it be on exactly?  Just because the answer is "there isn't one" doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 7):

All the references I'm finding - although some are 4-years old or older - indicate that there is no 64-bit version (at least not yest). Here's a reference on stack overflow: [Visual Studio 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit)
and an external one: http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0025/

This list from Microsoft of requirements for VS 2015 doesn't mention 64-bit processors at all: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs#2

Comment: 2017 RC just came out.  Guess what isn't yet 64-bit?

Comment: and also https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2255687-make-vs-scalable-by-switching-to-64-bit

Comment: 2019 is out now, still no x64 support apart from a few components https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/517541/vs-2019-downloaded-x64-version-installed-x86.html