# c# visual studio 2017 CPU profiling out of memory exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, out-of-memory, profiling

I've got a long running c# application that I'm profiling in visual studio 2017 community edition. Runs for about 2/3 hours before I stop the profiling (and application) to see the CPU usage. However I can see when its building the reports the memory usage increases by 3GB then throws an out of memory exception.

```
Profiling started.
Profiling process ID 7312 (test).
Starting data collection. The output file is C:\Users\jamie\Source\Repos\test(1).vspx
Profiler stopping.
Stopping data collection.
Merging collection data. Please wait...
Data is saved in file C:\Users\jamie\Source\Repos\test(1).vspx
Profiling finished.
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this or do I just have to get more memory?

Oddly the total memory usage on my machine is around 65% when it throws this so its not even using all my memory to build the profiling reports.

This is a fresh install of VS and its got all the default settings.

Comment: The profiler built into VS is a 32-bit program.  It is not capable of using all the memory in your machine, only a 64-bit program can do that.  Nor is it capable of handling that much profile data.  You'll have to produce less.

Comment: If you try do that in Visual Stduio 2013 it just crashes when analyzing the report.