# Does anyone have an issue with Visual Studio 2015 Data Tools crashing when running package?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, kingswaysoft

I can build SSIS packages without any issues, but almost every time I run the package from Visual Studio it will crash. Sometimes it will crash within seconds of running the package, other times it will run a few minutes and then crash.

The only error being logged to the Windows event log is:

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85
>   Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.17763.1, time stamp: 0xc3ae1887
>   Exception code: 0xc0000409
>   Fault offset: 0x000a5d0b
>   Faulting process id: 0x5bd4
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d4cdf2158d4ebd
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
>   Report Id: 760baa61-e6fb-4646-83f5-94ed566b1d4a
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

I have tried repairing and reinstalling Visual Studio (multiple times), reinstalling Data Tools, and also reinstalling Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (as I saw comments from others online with what I thought would be a similar ucrtbase.dll issue. This is a work computer, and others here have had the same issue in the past, but it seems to have been resolved for them after performing some of the steps I have already done. For a while we thought it was related to using the Balanced Data Distributor, but I have removed that altogether and am still having issues. Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Environment:

- Window 10 version 1809
- Visual Studio 2015 update 3
- SQL Server Data Tools 2015
- Kingswaysoft v10.2

Comment: The error is faulting on ucrtbase.dll. have you tried replacing/reinstalling this file? Also, what bit installation are you on: 32 or 64?

Comment: From what I could find, Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable should have been for ucrtbase.dll, so yes I have tried reinstalling it. 64-bit Windows, 32-bit apps.

Comment: Are you on 64-bit SQL Server and 64-bit Visual Studio?

Comment: 32-bit Visual Studio, connecting to a 64-bit SQL Server.

Comment: That may be your problem. Install VS 64-bit. I have seen Microsoft's product stack give cryptic errors at least once before and it was traced to a mismatch in the bit versions installed.

Comment: I have used this setup for years and never had an issue.

Comment: Wait, you're right. VS is a 32-bit application that can compile 64-bit. Brain fart. How about the Kingswaysoft? is that a 32 or 64 bit installation?

Comment: Just as of the past month or so.

Comment: There is no such thing as VS 64-bit (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit). That said, I too have experienced this behavior from time to time. Starting VS with /resetskippkgs has (and hasn't) worked, reinstall has (and hasn't) worked. Restructuring the package (breaking into two) has almost always worked as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, however restructuring the package isn't really an option here. I am having these crashes with the simplest of packages: pull from one source and push to a different target, with no in between steps. I did a full reinstall (reset) of Windows last night and reinstalled all my apps and still have this crashing issue today.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best (or right) answer, but rather a workaround. As I cannot perform my job with a buggy VS, I decided to try VS 2017 (with SSDT 2017, etc.) As of the past couple hours that has been working and has not crashed on me (yet). My workaround for now, until we can fully move to 2017, will be to create new projects in 2015 so that other developers will continue to be able to work with me, but then switch over to 2017 for testing.

If anyone comes around with a real solution to the issue (my guess is it's some combination of VS, SSDT, Windows, and other updates), please share.

Comment: For creating packages, can the VS2015 target the same version of SQL Server that VS2017 supports? As of this post, VS2017 can point to 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and I believe 2019. In other words, you shouldn't have to re-point packages simply when switching between versions of Visual Studio - you only change packages when pointing to different SQL Server versions.